# Magento "Allowed Countries" are not effecting in New Product "Country Of Manufacture"

Tags: php, magento, countries

I have to update the countries list in Magento, So i updated lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml and  "directory_country" table.

Now newly added countries are populating in the "Allow Countries" `(System >> Configuration >> General >> Countries Options )` dropdown in Magento Admin Panel.

Here, i selected some countries that what my Client Required, but these changes are not effecting in the "Countries of Manufacture" dropdown in the "New Product" Section, Here the "Country of Manufacture" dropdown populating all the countries including newly added countries.

But i need specific countries which are selected From "Allow Countries" Dropdown.

Comment: why should you restrict country of manufacture? Because product may come from any country. Allowed countries option only for placing an order from selected countries. So these two are different.

Comment: No, the Client required only specific Countries are to be populated in  "Country Of Manufacture" Dropdown